# Input stream to string

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

How do I get the string from input stream in order to make it the name of the file transferred over bluetooth?

When sending a file, I add file name to outputStream, then add "|" as a delimiter and afterwards I ad the file bytes array:

```
 try {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(myFile);
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis, 8 * 1024);
            bis.read(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);

            outStream.write(fileNameOut.getBytes());
            outStream.write("|".getBytes());
            outStream.write(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);

            outStream.flush();
            outStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("BT Connected", "disconnected", e);
        }
```

When receiving a file I want to get all bytes until "|" character and save them as string in order to become a filename for the new file to which bytes from bluetooth transfer will be written:

```
   try {
     try {
      int read;

// obtain a filename from inputStream
      BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(inStream);
      ByteArrayOutputStream buf = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
      int result = bis.read();
      while (result != -1) {
       buf.write((byte) result);
       result = bis.read();
      }
      //
      general.log("Bluetooth Connected", "file name: " + buf.toString());

      while ((read = inStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
       transferStatus = "sending";
       bytesRead += read;

       general.log("Bluetooth Connected", "odebrano: " + bytesRead + "bytes: ");

       fos.write(buffer, 0, read);
       transferStatus = "sent";
      }

     } finally {
      outStream.flush();
      inStream.close();
      mmSocket.close();
     }
    } catch (Exception e) {
     general.log("Bluetooth Connected", "======= Error receiving file: " + e);
    }
```

Presented code does not look for "|" character yet, since it does not even convert bytes to string and I have no idea why. How do I divide buffered stream into two parts: get string until "|" and save as filename, get the rest and write to file?

Comment: Hi @jacek_podwysocki, have you been able to transfer the file over bluetooth socket? Can you look at this please https://stackoverflow.com/q/46423934/2866141

Comment: Or share your code if you have done this please, I am stuck :(