# Android send audio file via Bluetooth using BluetoothChat example

Tags: android, audio, bluetooth

I am trying to send audio file via Bluetooth using the sample BluetoothChat code.

I have created a class that converts audio into bytes and vise-versa.

Here are the modifications I have made in the sample code

```
private void sendMessage(String message) {
    // Check that we're actually connected before trying anything
    if (mChatService.getState() != BluetoothChatService.STATE_CONNECTED) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.not_connected, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }

    // Check that there's actually something to send
    if (message.length() > 0) {
        // Get the message bytes and tell the BluetoothChatService to write

        byte[] send = message.getBytes();

        //Convert noti.mp3 into byte array (noti.mp3 is an audio file I am using for testing)
        try{send = Converter.convertAudioToBytes(path+"noti.mp3");}
        catch(Exception e){Logger.append("Error while converting audio into bytes", e);}

        mChatService.write(send);

        // Reset out string buffer to zero and clear the edit text field
        mOutStringBuffer.setLength(0);
        mOutEditText.setText(mOutStringBuffer);
    }
}
```

I am also adding some bytes at the end of the audio to identify the endOfFile on the receiving end.

On the receiving end I have updated the mHandler

```
//List to store bytes received from the other device 
private List<Byte> list = new ArrayList<Byte>();


case Constants.MESSAGE_READ:
    byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;

    //Status for end of data
    boolean endOfData = false;

    //Add bytes to the Array list
    for(int i=0;i<msg.arg1;i++){list.add(readBuf[i]);}

    // construct a string from the valid bytes in the buffer
    String readMessage = new String(readBuf, 0, msg.arg1);
    mConversationArrayAdapter.add(mConnectedDeviceName + ": " + readMessage);

    //Check if the received message contains this string
    //Also check if the length of the data is less than 990
    if(readMessage.contains("END OF AUDIO FILE") && msg.arg1<990){
        endOfData = true;
    }

    //Check if all the data has been received 
    if(endOfData)
    {
        try{
            Converter.convertBytesToAudio(list,path);
            mConversationArrayAdapter.add(mConnectedDeviceName + ": Audio saved!");
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            Logger.append("Error while converting bytes to audio", e);
        }
        finally{
            list.clear();
        }
    }
    break;
```

The code works fine for small audio files but when I send a file that is bigger than 3KB it does not properly receive the data and does not transfer it to audio properly.

I tried to send some long text like this

```
String str = "Message number ";
for(int i=0;i<1000;i++){message += str+i+" ,\n";}
byte[] send = message.getBytes();
mChatService.write(send);
```

on the receiving end I noticed, the messages received are not synchronized.

Can someone please help me solve this issue, or any other way to transfer audio messages via Bluetooth. I am trying to do something like WhatsApp audio messages but via Bluetooth.

Any help is appreciated.Thanks

Still waiting for an answer :( Please help

Comment: Why do you check if it is `<990`?

Comment: because the bytes I was receiving were 990 except the last one, which was end of audio message.